# Update child instead of creating new one in firebase !! connecting it with android recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn7Pd.png)  **ShowProjectAdapter.class**

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position ) {


        final showprojectdetails sRD = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);
        holder.projectnameTextView.setText(sRD.getTitle());

        holder.projectdescription.setText(sRD.getBody());
        holder.projecttag.setText(sRD.getTag());
        holder.org.setText(sRD.getOrg());
        holder.date.setText(sRD.getDate());
        holder.time.setText(sRD.getTime());
        holder.ori.setText(sRD.getOrigin());

//adding alert dialog on update button in the recyclerview
        holder.t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
//connecting layout attributes with the java class
                final TextView title = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pname);
                final TextView body = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pdescription);
                final TextView org = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.organization);
                final TextView tag = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.typetag);
                final TextView origin = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.country);

               
                
                builder.setView(dialogView);
            
//displaying the currect texts of the field using settext
                title.setText(sRD.getTitle());
                body.setText(sRD.getBody());
                origin.setText(sRD.getOrg());
                tag.setText(sRD.getTag());
                org.setText(sRD.getOrigin());

//save button of the alert dialog
                builder.setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


//firebase api to of saving current time and date in the firebase                   
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    final String date = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                    final String time = timeFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                     DatabaseReference databaseReference;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
//calling firebase api on alert dialog save button
// my firebase has structure -->databse name--> "query" ---> title name "android app"                     
  DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("query").child(title.getText().toString());
                        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("title", title.getText().toString());
                        map.put("date", date);
                        map.put("org", org.getText().toString());
                        map.put("origin", origin.getText().toString());
                        map.put("tag", tag.getText().toString());
                        map.put("time", time);
                        map.put("body", body.getText().toString());
                        ref.updateChildren(map);
                       [enter image description here][1]
                    }

//cancel button of the alert dialog
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();

            }

        });}
```

**Motive**  In the above code i'm tring to update the **firebase** data through android app,Where in the android app it is taking input to the user in **alert dialog** and displaying in into the **recyclerview** which hhave *update button* , i want to add the existence data on clicking that update button but its creating the new data instead of adding the existence one.

**Difficulty** My code creating the new child instead of adding the existence one

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("query").child(titl).updateChildren(map);  --> Changed my code to this and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think it would have been easier to understand the issue if you had posted a pic of your database. The question is not clear. Based on the comment in your code here's my understanding.

// my firebase has structure -->databse name--> "query" ---> title name "android app"

So, the title("android app") is a table name and it has children(title, date, org etc.,) which you're trying to update? If that is the case, try using setValue() to set value for each individual child.

```
String titleString = title.getText().toString()    
DatabaseReference m = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("query").child("android app");
m.child("title").setValue(titleString);
m.child("date").setValue(date);
```

If it doesn't work, probably you aren't referencing it properly. As I said if you can upload a pic of data stored in firebase it would be helpful in understanding the issue better. As I cannot imagine where the fields are being created( under query? or under "android app").

Do let us know if you have already rectified the issue.

> [**Ideally it should work if the database looks like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJCEJ.png)

Comment: " com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getText " --> getting this error by doing it by your method.

Comment: yes i know ! but stackoverfollow would't allowed mt to post picture , i was attaching it with the query earlier

Comment: Hey. I have updated the code. The conflict was because I named the string variable as "title" when you already had a textView Variable with the same name. Try now, it should work. And also I noticed that the image you tried to attach has been included as a part of your code. Try again and it will generate a line as follows-->                       [enter image description here][1]   ---Make sure it is outside the code block.

Comment: actually! i did using that way only , and then i got this error

Comment: oh okay ,i’ll attach database picture in the query !

Comment: There's an image I attached in the end of my answer. Check if that's how your database looks. Because if it doesn't, my code won't work.

Comment: i'm using title as in node and storing other data like (date,time description in it) , i've also attached the database picture  in the query,please take a look in it!

Comment: Try the code now. I made a few changes. Based on your database structure, this code should work. If it doesn't, share some feedback. Does it give any error? If so, what error do you get? Or is it creating new data like how it did for your code? Is it creating a new table "android app" with new data or is it creating new fields under the same table? Or it doesn't push the data into firebase at all. If possible do attach database picture after the function call. Or if you get any error post that too.

Comment: **020-07-09 23:46:47.132 21884-21884/com.example.feedback E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.feedback, PID: 21884
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method computerAcssesriees(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView ** i'm getting this error while doing it that way , also the child("android app") is dynamic as i'm storing project title there but still i've tried to do it as static first as you code it and its throwing this error

Comment: Good to know it worked. If you can say how you solved it, it would be helpful for others having similar issues. Also since it is solved can you close the question?